# Wordpress update errors

Tags: wordpress, content-management-system, wordpress-theming

I just went to update one of my wordpress sites. It was my first time updating a wordpress site.

When i went to update the update screen hung for 20 minutes saying "installing". The website home page was still displaying the maintenance notification. I looked this up and the consensus seemed to be to ftp to the site and delete the "maintenance" file. I did this and now the homepage displays:

`Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_front_page_template()......`

When i went to mysite/wp-admin it said, "wordpress has been installed, you now need to update your databases". So i pressed the "Update Databases" button upon which i'm presented with the error:

`Fatal error: Class 'WP_Theme' not found in.....`

I have a feeling i've done something very stupid. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Have you tried the [Wordpress support resources](http://wordpress.org/support/)?

Comment: you did make a backup before upgrading right? - what was your theme? have you just edited the default theme?

Comment: @lanzz No, actually i haven't. I thought i might have more luck here due to the size of the community

Comment: @garethdn: Your question is actually off-topic for this community. It does not have anything to do with programming. The Wordpress forums are likely a much better place to ask.

Comment: @KutF I'm embarrassed to say i didn't - it was my first time updating and didn't even think of it. I'm using the Academica Theme which i've edited slightly

Comment: try manually copying the latest wordpress files through FTP overrighting your install (except for the config.php , obviously). looks like something failed. this should sort it and ask you do update your DB.

Comment: I'll take a look at doing that now, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backup your current faulty setup via FTP.

Then download the wordpress version you were using from the [Release Archive](http://wordpress.org/download/release-archive/) and replace the files of your `wp-admin` and `wp-include` folders using FTP.

This should make your wordpress installation work again.

The problem about the database is probably because the update wasn't completed.

Comment: Could you tell me how i can find out what version of Wordpress i was using before i encountered this error?

Comment: Defined at `$wp_version` in `version.php` file found in `wp-includes` directory. If this file got overwritten, then I don't know how you'll get it...